# Extract 2 Entity from single word : dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have two entities 1. Product list, 2. Price list,
When user search product? I want to extract product & price both entities from a single word. How to achieve it ?

For example..... I have one list of product ( Laptop, LCD, Monitor) and another for price ( $ 50 , $ 44, $ 300 )

when user search "do you have laptop", I want to extract value "Yes we have laptop for $50"

[Here is both entity picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjCmW.png)

[This is price entity picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knKlW.png)

[This is product entity picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8gDC.png)

[This is intent picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoTWD.png)

[Expected Response picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spi5C.png)

[Getting This reponse picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSYvn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this response because you have assigned product value for price.
[image: This is where you are doing wrong].

Comment: Yes I assigned it intentionally because I want to get @ price entity value using the product value. As you know dialog flow get entity's main value when user pass synonymous.  So when I pass product name ? I hope it should look into @ price entity for $product name, and get main value from there @Ershadi

Comment: There seems a problem with your design too. You can use composite entities https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/developer-entities#developer_composite to get this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your price entity is wrong. There is a rule in dialogflow as mentioned in the attached picture [image: Refer this image]